# Exclude a dynamic value from cache with Wordpress Super Cache

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Super Cache plugin.

For some time I was looking for a solution, but without success. I need to disable the cache for one function in the file `functions.php`.

```
add_shortcode('custom_counter', 'example_shortcode');
function example_shortcode() {
    // Get custom counter option value
    $counter = get_option( 'wc-custom-counter' );
    return '<span class="custom-counter">' . $counter . ' rub.</span>';
}
```

This is shortcode is used on the created custom page. It is necessary that the data output by this shortcode does not fall into the page cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from [this old WSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70813/79855), you will find below the complete way to make it working.

Here we display a spinner loading icon [image] that will be replaced by the counter real non cached value through ajax. Javascript stays always active even in a cached page, so it can change anything needed on the page via Ajax or via any detected event. So there is **no need to exclude anything** in the plugin settings.

The replacement code:

```
// The shortcode
add_shortcode('custom_counter', 'customer_counter_shortcode');
function customer_counter_shortcode() {
    // Start buffering
    ob_start(); 

    // Using woocommerce existing animated spinner gif icon
    $loading_url = home_url( '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/select2-spinner.gif' );
    
    // Displaying a "Loading spinner icon + text to be replaced by Ajax value
    echo '<span class="custom-counter">
        <img id="loading-img" src="'.$loading_url.'" alt="Loading..." style="opacity:0.5; display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" />
        <span style="opacity:0.5;"> ' . _("loading…") . '</span>
    </span>';
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action': 'custom_counter',
                'custom-counter': true,
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('.custom-counter').text(result);
                console.log('response: '+result); // just for testing | TO BE REMOVED
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error); // just for testing | TO BE REMOVED
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered code
}

// The wordpress ajax hooked function (for logged in and non logged users)
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_counter', 'ajax_custom_counter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_counter', 'ajax_custom_counter');
function ajax_custom_counter() {
    if( isset($_POST['custom-counter']) && $_POST['custom-counter'] )
        echo get_option( 'wc-custom-counter' ); // Get option value

    exit();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

Comment: Loic, thank you! Is this for any page in the frontend?

Comment: Yes this should work for any page in frontend, when woocommerce plugin is enabled, as I am using `woocommerce_params` instead of enqueuing an external js file + `wp_localize_script()`

Comment: @АлександраКузнецова I have updated my answer code including an animated loading icon, loaded from woocommerce existing assets, that will be replaced by the real counter value (non cached) through Ajax. You will not need to add anything in cache plugin settings, as javascript stays active on cached pages.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot exclude a function from cache plugins. Instead you can exclude an URL (in WP Super Cache, go to 'Settings > WP Super Cache > Advanced' - 'Accepted Filenames & Rejected URIs' section).

So, call this function using AJAX instead calling directly and you can exclude the AJAX URL.

Here is the full code.

Add these in theme's **functions.php**:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_customer_counter', 'customer_counter_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customer_counter', 'customer_counter_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}

function customer_counter_ajax_handler() {      
    // Get custom counter option value
    $counter = get_option( 'wc-custom-counter' );
    echo $counter . ' rub.';
}
```

Replace all your shortcodes `[custom_counter]` instances with `<span class="customer_counter_shortcode">&nbsp;</span>`.

Add this script to theme's **footer.php**:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // AJAX handler
        data : { action : 'customer_counter' },
        type : 'POST',
        success : function( $result ){
            if( $result ) {
                $('.customer_counter_shortcode').html($result);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You can then exclude the AJAX URL - **/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=customer_counter**.

Comment: Could you provide an example of including a function in Ajax?

Comment: I have now added the AJAX code in the original answer.

Comment: But without a short code not adds the desired function to the front page.

Comment: You can't simply call a shortcode. Why can't you simply replace the shortcode with some `<span>` element and load the content using AJAX?

Comment: Because on the created page example.com/custom-new-page/ no hook. Dinamic content must be placed inside the page. If you know how, tell me, please. I think need another option, maybe need to write a script on the page itself to call the desired function on the page.

Comment: Where did you place the shortcode, whether in template or page content itself? I need to view the full code to provide a solution.

Comment: It was the complete code. I used the short code on any page I created, adding this line [custom_counter] in the content editor of the page in the admin panel.

Comment: Outsource WordPress, thank you! I see that the code works. Only script code will be on each page. In the answer above, I can use a shortcode and use it only on the page you need.