# Calling PHP function from wordpress using admin ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

i have a function in wordpress and would like to call it in ajax using wordpress admin ajax
this is the function

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'pixel_cookie_consent2' );

function pixel_cookie_consent2() {

$cookie = ( isset( $_COOKIE['moove_gdpr_popup'] ) ) ? $_COOKIE['moove_gdpr_popup'] : false;
$cookie = stripslashes( $cookie );
$cookie = json_decode( $cookie, true );

// disabled by default  
deactivate_plugins( '/woocommerce-conversion-tracking/conversion-tracking.php' );

// enabled based on user setting
if ( $cookie['thirdparty'] == 1 ) {
        activate_plugins( '/woocommerce-conversion-tracking/conversion-tracking.php' );
   }
}
```

this function disables the plugin before user accepts cookies (gdpr law).

When user accepts cookies the plugin is enabled and cookie is fired.

My problem is when i turn cache on this does not work properly because page is cached with plugin off and then it does not turn on, so i thought calling the function using ajax.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: what is the plugin?

Comment: This is the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/gdpr-cookie-compliance/ but it has not to do with the plugin I would like to call this function through ajax

Comment: I thought you wanted to activate a plugin if cookies are allowed. if that's the case, you'd need to import the plugin dynamically from js. you can't call your function with Ajax.

Comment: i thought i could do something like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322339/exclude-a-dynamic-value-from-cache-with-wordpress-super-cache